# Remove Zero from last in numeric in SQL Server from numeric

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a `numeric` column in SQL Server, and my values look like this:

```
 4.00
 6.25
 6.00
 6.80
10.00
12.00
```

I want to display like

```
4
6.25
6
6.8
10
12
```

Thank in advance

Comment: Display where? Formatting data is not database responsibility, you should do it where you display data.

Comment: Is it a numeric(18, 2)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just Pass your `Numeric` Value in `''` in `ROUND` Function as below :

```
SELECT ROUND('4.00', 2)

SELECT ROUND('6.25', 2)

SELECT ROUND('6.00', 2)

SELECT ROUND('6.80', 2)
```

**Result :**

[image]

Comment: Wrong if number is a float.

Comment: @Yogesh...thnx.

Answer (score 3):

You can try:

```
select round(CONVERT (VARCHAR(50), 6.00,128),2)
```

Comment: what is mean of ,128??

Comment: + 0 (default)-A maximum of 6 digits. Use in scientific notation, when appropriate.
+ 1 - Always 8 digits. Always use in scientific notation.
+ 2 -Always 16 digits. Always use in scientific notation.
+ 126, 128, 129 -Included for legacy reasons and might be deprecated in a future release. You can you using 1 of them.

Answer (score 0):

If you column data type is Numeric(18, 2), then you can make your own function:

```
use db_test;
go

create function dbo.trunc_numeric (@value numeric(18, 2))
returns varchar(20)
as
begin
    declare @a bigint = (@value * 100) % 100;
    declare @b bigint = (@value * 100) % 10;
    if @a = 0
        return cast(cast(@value as numeric(18, 0)) as varchar(20));
    if @a <> 0 and @b = 0
        return cast(cast(@value as numeric(18, 1)) as varchar(20));
    return cast(@value as varchar(20));
end

select dbo.trunc_numeric(10.123);
select dbo.trunc_numeric(10.120);
select dbo.trunc_numeric(10.100);
select dbo.trunc_numeric(10.000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this way

```
SELECT  ROUND(CAST(col AS VARCHAR), 2) AS [Number]
FROM(
     SELECT 4.00 AS col
     UNION ALL
     SELECT 6.25 AS col
     UNION ALL
     SELECT 6.00 AS col
     UNION ALL
     SELECT 6.80 AS col
     UNION ALL
     SELECT 10.00 AS col
     UNION ALL
     SELECT 12.00 AS col
)x
```